# Context manager to temporarily drop indexes and constraints on a table

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

I'm importing millions of rows into a PostgreSQL database using a [foreign data wrapper](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/postgres-fdw.html). To speed this up I've written this [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) to `DROP` all the indexes and constraints (except the primary key) on the target table for the duration of the data move and reinstate them afterwards:

```
import logging
import types
import typing
from psycopg2 import _psycopg, sql


class RawTable():
    def __init__(self, cursor: _psycopg.cursor, table_name: str, schema_name: str = 'public'):
        self.cursor = cursor
        self.schema_name = schema_name
        self.table_name = table_name

        self.constraints: typing.List[typing.Tuple[str, str]] = []
        self.index_definitions: typing.List[str] = []

    def __enter__(self) -> None:
        self.store_and_delete_constraints()
        self.store_and_delete_indexes()

    def store_and_delete_constraints(self) -> None:
        self.cursor.execute(
            """
            SELECT pg_constraint.conname,
                   pg_get_constraintdef(pg_constraint.oid)
              FROM pg_constraint
              JOIN pg_class ON pg_constraint.conrelid = pg_class.oid
              JOIN pg_namespace ON pg_namespace.oid = pg_class.relnamespace
             WHERE pg_constraint.contype <> 'p' AND
                   pg_class.relname = %s AND
                   pg_namespace.nspname = %s
            """,
            (self.table_name, self.schema_name)
        )
        for (name, constraint_sql) in self.cursor.fetchall():
            self.constraints.append((name, constraint_sql))
            logging.debug("Dropping constraint {}".format(name))
            self.cursor.execute(
                sql.SQL('ALTER TABLE {}.{} DROP CONSTRAINT {}').format(
                    sql.Identifier(self.schema_name),
                    sql.Identifier(self.table_name),
                    sql.Identifier(name)
                )
            )

    def store_and_delete_indexes(self) -> None:
        self.cursor.execute(
            """
            SELECT index_class.relname,
                   pg_get_indexdef(pg_index.indexrelid)
              FROM pg_index
              JOIN pg_class AS index_class ON pg_index.indexrelid = index_class.oid
              JOIN pg_class AS table_class ON pg_index.indrelid = table_class.oid
              JOIN pg_namespace ON pg_namespace.oid = index_class.relnamespace
             WHERE NOT pg_index.indisprimary AND
                   pg_index.indisvalid AND
                   table_class.relname = %s AND
                   pg_namespace.nspname = %s
            """,
            (self.table_name, self.schema_name)
        )
        for (name, index_sql) in self.cursor.fetchall():
            self.index_definitions.append(index_sql)
            logging.debug("Dropping index {}".format(name))
            self.cursor.execute(sql.SQL('DROP INDEX {}').format(sql.Identifier(name)))

    def __exit__(
            self,
            exception_type: typing.Type[BaseException],
            exception: BaseException,
            traceback: types.TracebackType
    ) -> bool:
        self.restore_constraints()
        self.restore_indexes()
        return exception_type is None

    def restore_constraints(self) -> None:
        logging.debug("Restoring {} constraint(s)".format(len(self.constraints)))
        constraint_definitions = [
            sql.SQL("ADD CONSTRAINT {} {}").format(
                sql.Identifier(name),
                sql.SQL(constraint_sql)
            ) for name, constraint_sql in self.constraints
        ]
        self.cursor.execute(
            sql.SQL("ALTER TABLE {}.{} {}").format(
                sql.Identifier(self.schema_name),
                sql.Identifier(self.table_name),
                sql.SQL(', ').join(constraint_definitions)
            )
        )

    def restore_indexes(self) -> None:
        logging.debug("Restoring {} index(es)".format(len(self.index_definitions)))
        for index_definition in self.index_definitions:
            self.cursor.execute(index_definition)
```

Example use:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor, RawTable(cursor, 'target_table'):
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO target_table (…) SELECT … FROM huge_table')
```

(Log level is expected to be set up elsewhere, hence the lack of a `logging.basicConfig` or equivalent call.)